# How can I cluster my snowflake table on the entirety of a VARCHAR column?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The Snowflake documentation is quite clear that only the first 5 characters of a VARCHAR are being used in clustering.

See  in ["Important Notes"](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html)

I thought about using HASH() on the VARCHAR but

```
SHOW FUNCTIONS LIKE 'HASH';
```

tells me it is not usable for Clustering (see column *valid_for_clustering*)

Is there another way/function I could use to cluster on my entire VARCHAR?

Comment: You can rebuild the table with an additional integer column that identifies values in your varchar column and cluster using that. Does that column only take a few and finite number of values?

Comment: Yes, I agree with this solution because this varchar value is in fact a lookup to another table where I could easily add a unique number.
My varchar takes 129 different values, which shrinks to 29 if using only 5 characters.

Comment: Unless the first x characters in different values are the same then there is no benefit from creating a cluster key that is longer than x characters. If you know that, for example, limiting yourself to just the first 15 chars will give unique values you could cluster using substrings e.g. create or replace table t3 (vc varchar) cluster by (SUBSTRING(vc, 1, 5), SUBSTRING(vc, 6, 5), SUBSTRING(vc, 11, 5));

Comment: In our case, this is a 100 characters field free for the user to enter so we have no idea which characters combination to use. Interesting idea though